# Chrome Headless browser not working for specific website

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I am trying to implement selenium + Java + Chrome Headless for my application but I am getting exception "element not interactable". I have tried different window-size options but no luck.
While I am running the same code in interactive mode in chrome browser it is working fine.
Also I tried to run the same headless options for another website it is working fine.

Is there anything I am missing here. Below is the code for ChromeOptions and error description.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
        //options.addArguments("--window-size=1240,800");
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

**Logs-**

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
  (Session info: headless chrome=85.0.4183.121)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'OM', ip: '172.XX.XX.XX', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 85.0.4183.121, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 85.0.4183.87 (cd6713ebf92fa..., userDataDir: C:\Users\\AppData\Lo...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:55464}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID:
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `--window-size=1920,1080` but it is getting overridden by  `--start-maximized` flag.

Try removing this line `options.addArguments("--start-maximized")` and run the code.

Comment: I have tried by removing the line "start-maximized". Still facing same issue of element not interactable.

Comment: Can you check in your code if you are maximizing window using driver instance.

Something like this.
`driver.manage().window().maximize();`

Comment: Yes i have verified there is no maximize window code, Still not working for particular website only which is my project. On rest other websites it is working fine and not getting errors for element not interractable. Note-locators XPath is correct because same is working fine in interractable mode.

Comment: okay cool. I was also having problems in headless mode but above solutions worked for me. In your case may be it's something else. Just a last suggestion. Can you try with different window sizes.